# pygtk progressbar is not working

Tags: python, pygtk

when my program receiving new file file is copied fine but progress bar is not moving... if possible please suggest me a better algo.. Thanks

```
    def filetransfer(self):
        s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        s.bind(('',30098))
        s.listen(1)
        data='val'
        while True:
            request = s.accept()
            if request!=None:
                new_sock,addr=request
                break
        print 'Connected by', addr
        destination=open(data,'wb')
        while data!='':
            time.sleep(0.01)
            start=time.time()
            data=new_sock.recv(1024)
            end=time.time()
            xact=int(end-start)
            destination.write(data)
            self.run(xact)      
       new_sock.close()
       s.close()
       return


    def run_(self,xact):
       gobject.timeout_add(xact, self.update)
    def update(self):       
        if self.progressbar.get_fraction() >= 1.0:
             value = 0.0
         else:
             value = self.progressbar.get_fraction() + 0.1
         self.progressbar.set_fraction(value) 
         percent = value * 100
         percent = str(int(percent))
         self.progressbar.set_text(percent + "%")
         return True
```

Comment: You don't even say what gui framework you're using

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496814/progress-bar-not-updating-during-operation.  Accepted answer completely satisfies this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why so many people answer in the comments...

You need to call "Update()" inside of a loop, as in the question posted in the comment above.

[Progress bar not updating during operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496814/progress-bar-not-updating-during-operation)

However, if this doesn't work, please update the question so I can help you further.